# JaxB Validation Event Locator - wrong object references

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

I was just looking to below questions:
[How to get validation events with JaXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295028/how-to-get-validation-events-with-jaxb)

[Validate nested object from complex object using jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953248/validate-nested-object-from-complex-object-using-jaxb)

I had a similar problem so I tried these solutions but I found something odd:

**Customer Validation**

```
package com.oner.jaxb.test;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;
public class CustomerValidator implements ValidationEventHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getMessage());
        System.out.println(event.getLocator().getObject());
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Customers**

```
package com.oner.jaxb.test.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customers {

    private List<Customer> customers = 
            new ArrayList<Customer>();

    @XmlElement(name="customer")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customers [customers=" + customers + "]";
    }

}
```

**Customer**

```
package com.oner.jaxb.test.entities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Customer {

    private String name;

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = 
        new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [name=" + name + ", phoneNumbers=" + phoneNumbers + "]";
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
package com.oner.jaxb.test.entities;

public class PhoneNumber {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PhoneNumber []";
    }

}
```

**JabxbTest**

```
package com.oner.jaxb.test;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.oner.jaxb.test.entities.Customer;
import com.oner.jaxb.test.entities.Customers;
import com.oner.jaxb.test.entities.PhoneNumber;

public class JaxbTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customers customers = new Customers();

        Customer customer1 = new Customer();
        customer1.setName("123456");
        customer1.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer1.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());
        customer1.getPhoneNumbers().add(new PhoneNumber());

        customers.getCustomers().add(customer1);

        Customer customer2 = new Customer();
        customer2.setName("234");

        customers.getCustomers().add(customer2);

        try {

            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
            Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("resources/customer.xsd"));

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customers.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setSchema(schema);
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            CustomerValidator customerValidator = new CustomerValidator();
            marshaller.setEventHandler(customerValidator);

            marshaller.marshal(customers, new DefaultHandler());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**customer.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="customers">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="customer"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
                <xs:element ref="phone-number" maxOccurs="2"/>
             </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="phone-number">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

Now, here is the funny thing.

When I run the example using Java 1.6, I got below

```
cvc-maxLength-valid: Value '123456' with length = '6' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringMaxSize5'.
Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]]
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '123456' of element 'name' is not valid.
Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]]
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element '{phone-number}' is expected at this point.
Customers [customers=[Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]], Customer [name=234, phoneNumbers=[]]]]
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element is expected at this point.
Customer [name=234, phoneNumbers=[]]
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'customer' is not complete. One of '{phone-number}' is expected.
Customers [customers=[Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]], Customer [name=234, phoneNumbers=[]]]]
```

And with Java 1.7

```
cvc-maxLength-valid: Value '123456' with length = '6' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringMaxSize5'.
Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]]
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '123456' of element 'name' is not valid.
Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]]
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone-number'. No child element is expected at this point.
PhoneNumber []
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'customer'. No child element is expected at this point.
Customer [name=234, phoneNumbers=[]]
cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'customer' is not complete. One of '{phone-number}' is expected.
Customers [customers=[Customer [name=123456, phoneNumbers=[PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber [], PhoneNumber []]], Customer [name=234, phoneNumbers=[]]]]
```

My qustion and my expectations:

1. I see 2 errors for first Customer objects, both regarding the Name field length, but why do I have get 2 validation errors ??
2. "No child element is expected at this point" error is raised for second Customer but it shoud be the first, that has 3 PhoneNumber element, which should be max. 2
3. "One of '{phone-number}' is expected" error is raised for Customers element, which is maybe acceptable, but I also expect this error for seconds Customer element, which has no PhoneNumber element where min. is 1
4. Java 7 raised error for missing PhoneNumber on second customer, which is good, but it locates the honeNumber object is the Customer. I expect to see the Customer element also.

Can someone tell me what's going on ? Is ValidationEventLocator works correct or did I expect too much from JaxB?

Thanks

Comment: I think you really expect too much from JAXB. There is a good distance between the schema and the schema-derived classes. Sometimes you get your models twisted in a way that you hardly recognize them. I would not rely on schema validation to infer errors in the object structures. An excellent question, though.

Comment: Well, this is what I'm doing so far, but somehow I hoped to use JaxB validation like javax.validation, but it seems its not possible. I guess my best option is to annotate those fields with javax.validation annotations and validate them. But that also means double work + everytime a schema rule changes, I need to apply it to validation rules as well.

Comment: If this helps (not sure), you can use my `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` which can add arbitrary annotations to the schema-derived classes.

Comment: @lexicore, I found another interesting plugin, *krasa-jaxb-tools*, which adds JSR-303 annotations equivalents of XSD Schame Validation rules.

Comment: Interesting. Please consider posting an answer with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little digging, I found an interesting plugin, *krasa-jaxb-tools*, which adds JSR-303 annotations equivalents of XSD Schame Validation rules. Examples seems promissing: [github repo](https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools)